# Is there a way to find a generic type by its type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types

I have such type

```
public abstract class BaseType<T>
```

And i have another type that derives from this one

```
public class TypeX: BaseType<SomeRandomType>
```

Is there a way to create an instance of `TypeX` knowing only that it derives from `BaseType` using `SomeRandomType` as `T` and not knowing its name?

Basically, I need some method that takes `SomeRandomType` (either as `typeof(SomeRandomType)` or just `new SomeRandomType()`) as a parameter and returns `TypeX`'s instance

Comment: There could be multiple types that inherit from `BaseType<SomeRandomType>` though. Which one would you choose?

Comment: Do you know the name of the assembly that you expect to find the type in? E.g. are all implementations in one assembly, and you're just looking to find the first concrete implementation at runtime?

Comment: The "clean" way of solving this would typically be through some kind of factory or dependency injection container where types or instances are explicitly registered, rather than spooky action at a distance where you hunt for the type through unwritten rules.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: It's not too uncommon to iterate through types of an assembly looking for ones that match a condition (e.g. implement a specific interface) for various reasonable purposes such as registering them with DI.

Comment: @Sweeper, in my case there can't be more than one type that inherits. But I got your point, I can take the first one found, it will work in my particular scenario

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson, all inherited types lies in the same assembly as a base type

Comment: @EricJ.: I'd argue that *purpose* is reasonable, but not necessarily the mechanism -- I prefer my wiring to be out in the open and explicit. I guess I'm just old school. :P (Attributes are just about the only thing I'd argue are "OK" for this, since they clearly mark a metadata purpose and you can search for their use.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I understand your point of view. I feel when a system is large enough, moving up a level of abstraction and following clear conventions can become necessary. Have a look at how MediatR registers classes with DI. There isn't ambiguity, and the purpose of each is clearly defined via interface contract. https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/Registration/ServiceRegistrar.cs

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension function to help you find out whether the types you're looping through in your assembly are assignable to your generic type and then take the single match found and use the `Activator` class to create an instance of that object.

**Extension function**

```
public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(this Type givenType, Type genericType)
{
    foreach (Type it in givenType.GetInterfaces())
    {
        if (it.IsGenericType &&
            it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (givenType.IsGenericType &&
        givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    Type? baseType = givenType.BaseType;
    if (baseType is null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
}
```

**Solution**

```
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Single(type =>
        type.IsClass &&
        !type.IsAbstract &&
        type.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(BaseType<>)));

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

**Edit**

You might want to fetch the assembly differently based on your use case, but the rest should work the same way.

**Second edit**

If you're searching for a class inheriting exactly `BaseType<SomeRandomType>` then you don't even need this extension method I provided before, all you have to do is this:

```
Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Single(type =>
        type.IsClass &&
        !type.IsAbstract &&
        type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(BaseType<SomeRandomType>)));

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

And in case you only have the type of that generic argument, this should help you out:

```
Type someRandomType = typeof(SomeRandomType);

Type type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Single(type =>
        type.IsClass &&
        !type.IsAbstract &&
        type.BaseType != null &&
        type.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
        type.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.Length == 1 &&
        type.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.Single() == someRandomType);

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Hmm, I think, this code will give me first type that inherits `BaseType<T>`, I am trying to get the specific child, based on type-parameter. I give `typeof(SomeRandomType)` and the method return me an instance of `TypeX`, cause `TypeX:` inherits `BaseType<SomeRandomType>` (from my example in question).
Also, `CreateInstance()` return an object, which does not really suit me cause I would need to make a cast, to `TypeX`

Comment: @ViktorHusiev I see, I misunderstood at first. I could easily modify this code to search for a specific generic parameter of SomeRandomType. However, it won't solve the second part of the problem, which is the fact that the result of `CreateInstance()` is an object. You'd need to cast it to TypeX, but since you don't know that you're searching for TypeX exactly, you can't do so. What are you planning to do with this object further? How can you invoke it's specific methods further down the line if you don't know which exact type you're looking for? :)

Comment: If you provide the code for searching generic parameters it will be great, thanks a lot) this is one of my problems actually:)
The idea is to inherit from an abstract type with a specific method and call it from children. Some child types may override the logic of this method, but it should be in every type.

Comment: @ViktorHusiev check out the 2nd edit, is this what you're looking for? Or are you saying that you'll only have `SomeRandomType` which will be `T` and you don't know about abstract class `BaseType<>` either?

Comment: @ViktorHusiev Anyway... I added both samples so you pick what suits your needs.

Comment: yeah, I know about `BaseType<>`, so your sample do its work, thanks a lot;) unfortunately, I didn't find a way to make an instance without casting, so I guess I will need to find another solution(

Comment: @ViktorHusiev I'm unaware of what's the actual problem you're trying to solve, therefore I can't propose anything but the thing you're asking for. :)

`Activator` will in fact create an instance of the found type, but the return type from the method is an object because the type you're passing as a method parameter into `CreateInstance` method is not known at the compile time. That's why I asked what are you planning to do with that object after it's created. If you know the type and name of the method you're willing to invoke when thinking about it, maybe your approach is wrong.